# php get ip from proxy

Tags: php, proxy, ip

I think I'm not understanding this well...

I'm developing a php script, which inserts a new row in my table. But there's one field named 'ip_address', and I want to use a proxy which I have, to change ip address, to not insert always the same ip (the server of my website).

I'm doing this:

```
$loginpassw = 'login:passw';
$proxy_ip = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$proxy_port = 'xx';
$url = "http://www.domain.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

How to obtain the changed ip? I want obtain it, and insert it in database.

Best regards, Daniel

EDIT: **What I really want is not being detected I'm doing through the same ip...**

Comment: what ur talking about is [IP Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing). This is illegal except for some cases

Answer (score 1):

The script receiving the GET query should be able to obtain clients IP address by accessing this variable: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. This should return the address of the proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function Get_Real_IpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    if (!$ip)
       $ip = '';
    return $ip;
}
```